# How to remove the accelerator hot key '&' character?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-2007, acceleratorkey

I'm using the `'&'` character for using accelerator keys with my `TLabel` controls.
In this way, the user can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Character after the &</kbd> in order to focus controls on the form.

**Example:**

```
var
  MyLabel : TLabel;
  MyEdit : TEdit;
begin
  MyEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  MyEdit.Left := 20;
  MyEdit.Top := 40;
  MyEdit.Parent := Self;

  MyLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  MyLabel.FocusControl := MyEdit;
  MyLabel.Caption := '&Test';
  MyLabel.Left := 20;
  MyLabel.Top := 20;
  MyLabel.Parent := Self;
end;
```

In this case, `MyLabel` appears with the `'T'` character underlined and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> causes `MyEdit` to be focused.

[image]

How can I get `MyLabel.Caption` without the `'&'` character? Is there any built in function for doing this?

I'm expecting to get `'Test'` string instead of `'&Test'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for the [`StripHotkey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.StripHotkey) function.